# Stumped on this typescript error: "No overload matches this call"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

***ForgotPassword.tsx***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import ArrowBackOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackOutlined';
import EmailField from "components/Welcome/Fields/EmailField";
import { Link } from '@reach/router';
import { auth } from 'db/index';




interface NaviProps {
  gobackToSignIn: () => any;
}

export interface ForgetProps {
  handleForget: (forgetVars: { email: string }) => any;
  textFieldVariant?: "outlined" | "filled" | "standard";
  emailValidator?: (value: string) => boolean;
}


const INITIAL = { text: "", err: "" };

const Forget: React.FC<ForgetProps & NaviProps> = ({
  gobackToSignIn,
  handleForget,
  textFieldVariant = "filled",
  emailValidator = (e) => !!e,
}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(INITIAL);
   const [emailHasBeenSent, setEmailHasBeenSent] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = (event: any ,
     email:{ text: string} ) => {
   const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
           if (name === "userEmail") {
             setEmail(value);
           }
         };

 handleForget = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        auth
        .sendPasswordResetEmail(email.text)
        .then(() => {
          setEmailHasBeenSent(true);
          setTimeout(() => {setEmailHasBeenSent(false)}, 3000);
        })
        .catch(() => {
        //   setError("Error resetting password");
        console.log('Error resetting password')
        });
    };
  return (
    <>
      <IconButton aria-label="go back" onClick={gobackToSignIn}>
        <ArrowBackOutlinedIcon color="action" />
      </IconButton>
      <Box p={2} pb={6}>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="textSecondary" align="center">
          <b>Forget Your Password</b>
        </Typography>
        <br />
        <EmailField {...{ email, setEmail, textFieldVariant, loading }} />

        <FormControl margin="none" fullWidth>
          <Button
            onClick={handleForget}
            style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
            size="large"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            fullWidth >
            Reset my Password
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
export default Forget;
```

***Error***

```
<Button
            onClick={handleForget}
            style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
            size="large"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            fullWidth >
            Reset my Password
          </Button>
```

```js
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "outlined" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '(forgetVars: { email: string; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
      Types of parameters 'forgetVars' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Property 'email' is missing in type 'MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>' but required in type '{ email: string; }'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "outlined" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: string; onClick: (forgetVars: { email: string; }) => any; style: { textTransform: "none"; }; size: "large"; variant: "contained"; color: "primary"; fullWidth: true; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '(forgetVars: { email: string; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Types of parameters 'forgetVars' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Property 'email' is missing in type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' but required in type '{ email: string; }'.
```

Comment: This message occurs when you use mui or styled component or others like those, just make sure that your attributes match your interfaces in that component.

Comment: This code is really weird, there are two functions called handleForget and one of them looks like it was copy and pasted from a class component and the error rely on the fact that one of them can't be assigned to OnClick, in that case `handleForget: (forgetVars: { email: string }) => any;`

Answer (score 1):

From your error:

`Type '(forgetVars: { email: string; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.`.

This means you have one definition:

```js
(forgetVars: { email: string }) => any;
```

However it can't find overloaded function handleForget:

```js
(event: MouseEventHandler => any);
```

**Update:** Also if you decide to replace `handleForget` in the middle of your component (DON'T) - just create a new function

```js
const handleForgetImpl = (event: MouseEventHandler) ...
```

that you use for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error description it seems that there are no properties for the `Button` type. This may be because you are using an incorrect version of the `@types/react-native` package. You should consider upgrading the version of this package and verify that the new version has the features you need.